# print mysql table in PHP

Tags: php, html

I have a code to print data in tabulor form but its printing data in table below, I want to print it to the side by side ( see attached pic)

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT  player as AM FROM combine where name ='amit mantri';";
$sql .= "SELECT  player as NIk FROM combine where name ='nikhil parab'";
if($connection->multi_query($sql))
    {
        do{
            $result = $connection->store_result();
            $finfo = $result->fetch_fields();
            //echo($finfo['']);
         echo "<table border='1'>";
            foreach($finfo as $f)
            {
                echo "<td>"." ".$f->name."</td>";
            }
            echo "</tr>";
             while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
            {
                echo "<tr>";
                foreach($row as $v)
                {
                echo "<tr>";

                    echo " "."<td>".$v."</td>";
                }
                echo "</tr>";

            }
            //print_r($finfo);

    } while($connection->more_results() && $connection->next_result());

}
?>
```

**Please see expected results**

It is getting display like this:

[image]

But should be like this....

[image]

Comment: You need to delete the tr-tag in the inner foreach loop

Comment: alrrady checked that, did not helped               <code> </code

Comment: Is your query returning expected output?

Comment: yes its returning like correct, i attached screenshot of expected and actual

Comment: No, your query is **not correct**. You do not have _one_ query here, you have two, that you execute with `multi_query`. So your loop does never encounter _one_ “record” that contains both the AM and the NIk value, but it only comes across them as individual records, one containing the AM value, the other the NIk value. And because those are two different records, you get two table rows for them as well.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the expected output if your query and way of traversing through data is correct.

Your code was missing some opening and closing  tags and also I replaced  with  in the heading row.

You were adding both columns as rows because of missing  tags.

```
 <?php
$sql = "SELECT  player as AM FROM combine where name ='amit mantri';";
$sql .= "SELECT  player as NIk FROM combine where name ='nikhil parab'";
if($connection->multi_query($sql))
    {
        do{
            $result = $connection->store_result();
            $finfo = $result->fetch_fields();
            //echo($finfo['']);
         echo "<table border='1'>";
            echo "<tr>";
              foreach($finfo as $f)
              {
                 echo "<th>"." ".$f->name."</th>";

              }
            echo "</tr>";
             while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
            {
                echo "<tr>";
                foreach($row as $v)
                {


                    echo " "."<td>".$v."</td>";
                    echo " "."<td>".$v."</td>";
                }
                echo "</tr>";

            }
           echo "</table>";
            //print_r($finfo);

    } while($connection->more_results() && $connection->next_result());

}
?>
```

Comment: Please **edit** your answer and show clearly what you did to fix it and how it works to fix the issue.  Thanks.

Comment: with this additonal column created but existing table header Am and NIK still the same below each other, i would need them to be left and right

Comment: @moreshwarpantwalavalkar Please check my updated answer.

Comment: One thing more this will only rectify the structure of the table, further you will have to update your query also for correct result.

Comment: May i know what changes needed at query? I am here trying to display owner AM and NIK where all the players assign to them should be displayed in table row

Comment: You need to run two separate queries for them and them get their results in separate variable to achieve what you want.